# compatible python literals for python2 and python3

Tags: python

In python 3 I write

```
s = '\u0300'
```

and I get a single unicode character, but that doesn't work in python2, I get a string of various characters.

python2 seems to want:

```
s = u'\u0300'
```

so that I must check `sys.version_info` in order to know if I'm running python 2 or 3 and use the former or the latter accordingly.

Is there a way to write the assignment in a way that works in both versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most compatible way is to use the `six` module or a similar compatibility shim:

```
import six

s = six.u('\u0300')
```

`six` is available on PyPI, and is extremely broadly used and well-tested.

Another alternative is:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals 

s = '\u0300'
```

But, this can conflict with a number of Python 2 expectations, that string items can contain bytes. With `unicode_literals` on, string literals will be silently, almost magically upgraded to Unicode strings. Python culture often favors explicit over implicit.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 (starting from 3.3 IIRC) supports `u''` string literals. Or you can use

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

to get Python3-compatible string literals in Python 2. This statement is no-op in Python 3.

Comment: from __future__ import unicode_literals (need to edit)